# How to connect to Microsoft Dynamic NAV 5.0?

Tags: wcf, axapta, navision, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I need to implement connection between **Microsoft Dynamics AX**, **Microsoft Dynamics Navision 5.0** and external system via **WCF Service**.

> External System ---->WCF service ---> Axapta
>
> External System ---->WCF service ---> Navision 5.0

I've done with integration to **Microsoft Dynamics AX** via `Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.dll` and now i need to connect to **Navision 5.0**.

Is there a `BusinessConnectorNet` for **NAV 5.0** exists or some other ways to connect?

Comment: Nope. Nav 5 is not suppoting .Net assemblies. Only com automations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C/FRONT but this granule have to be in the NAV licence
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nav_developer/2008/04/19/beginners-guide-how-connect-to-nav-from-a-net-project-using-cfront/

Comment: No problem - let me know if you're having problems